# Angular 6: createComponent in lifecycle hook issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically create a component and have the Angular 6 code setup like this

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="defaultToTrue">
  <div #entry></div>
</div>
```

TS:

Before constructor

```
@ViewChild ('entry', {read: ViewContainerRef}) entry: ViewContainerRef;
```

Component creation:

```
const entryFormFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryFormComponent);
const entryComponent = this.entry.createComponent(entryFormFactory);`
```

If I put the above two lines in `ngAfterContentInit()`, I get the error:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

If I put it in `ngAfterViewInit()`, I get the error:

> Expression changed after it was checked

It works only when I wrap it in a `setTimeout` which I shouldn't have to do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element labeled with #parent template variable is wrapped inside a div with an *ngIf. However, *ngIf would remove the element from the DOM based on the expression. That means at the moment when the class is created, @Viewchild is referencing an undefined, non existing element, the lifecycle hook not being run yet.
I suggest you replace *ngIf with [hidden].

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkm8a1)

Comment: This is what I have been trying to do. I get the error "Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined". I forgot to mention that I am using Angular 6 if that matters.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that... I updated Angular version in demo and it is still working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doycev

Comment: I recreated the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvxn6w . I didn't think that wrapping the template reference in a structural directive could've caused the issue

Comment: The issue is *ngIf of course. I replaced with [hidden] and it works :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkm8a1